# How to get this data in jQuery each function? help me to solve this issue

Tags: jquery

```
 function check_businessHours() {
      for (var i = 1; i <= 7; i++) {
        var weekday = document.getElementById('weekday'+i);
        var opening_time = document.getElementById('opening_time'+i);
        var closing_time = document.getElementById('closing_time'+i);
        var close = document.getElementById('close'+i);
        var always = document.getElementById('always'+i);
        if (opening_time.value == "" && closing_time.value == "") {
          if (close.checked == true || always.checked == true) {
              $('#check_business').html('');
              $('#check_business').removeClass('bg-danger');
          } else {
            var value = weekday.value+' business hours required';

            console.log(value)
          }
        } else {
            $('#check_business').html('');
            $('#check_business').removeClass('bg-danger');
        }
      }
    }
```

Its return in console log like that

```
Saturday business hours required
Sunday business hours required
Monday business hours required
Wednesday business hours required
Thursday business hours required
```

I want to return in a div given below but i can't to do this. I can't get way to solve this issue

```
<div id="check_business" class="check-input"></div>
```

Can anyone help me to fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Empty the DIV at the beginning of the loop, then append a line for each day that requires hours.

```js
function check_businessHours() {
  for (var i = 1; i <= 7; i++) {
    $("check_business").empty().removeClass("bg-danger");
    var weekday = document.getElementById('weekday' + i);
    var opening_time = document.getElementById('opening_time' + i);
    var closing_time = document.getElementById('closing_time' + i);
    var close = document.getElementById('close' + i);
    var always = document.getElementById('always' + i);
    if (opening_time.value == "" && closing_time.value == "") {
      if (!(close.checked || always.checked)) {
        $("#check_business").append(`<div>${weekday.value} business hours required</div>`).addClass("bg-danger");

        console.log(value)
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Which ones are missing? Can you create a [mcve] that demonstrates the problem?

Answer (score 0):

The DIV clearing needs to be before the loop starts, else it'll only contain the last element.

```
function check_businessHours() 
{
    $("check_business").empty().removeClass("bg-danger");

    for (var i = 1; i <= 7; i++) 
    {
        var weekday = document.getElementById('weekday'+i);
        var opening_time = document.getElementById('opening_time'+i);
        var closing_time = document.getElementById('closing_time'+i);
        var close = document.getElementById('close'+i);
        var always = document.getElementById('always'+i);

        if (opening_time.value == "" && closing_time.value == "") 
        {
            if (!(close.checked || always.checked)) 
            {
                $("#check_business").append(`<div>${weekday.value} business hours required</div>`).addClass("bg-danger");
                console.log(value)
            }
        } 
    }
}
```

Comment: Understood, could you please supply, hand coded, what you want the DIV "check_business" to contain given a set of days/hours. This will help those of us, willing to help you understand precisely what result you are after.

Comment: Sloved successfully .   Thanks